# Numerical ODE solution with partial derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We had a numerical method for the solution of an ODE of the form
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+h_n(f(t_n,y_n)+\frac{h_n}{2}f'(t_n,y_n))$$

Where $f(t_n,y_n)=3y-2t$

Now the solution treats the partial derivatives of $f'(t_n,y_n)$ as a sum.

Why do we use them as a sum $f_t+f_y$? Shouldn't it be a vector $(f_t,f_y)^T$

Comment: You are missing the squares on $h_n$ in the last terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in several comments in previous questions, you want to use the second degree Taylor polynomial
$$
y(t+h)=y(t)+y'(t)h+\frac12y''(t)h^2+O(h^3)
$$
as approximation for the next point on the trajectory. The second derivative of $y$ is
$$
y''(t)=\frac{d}{dt}y'(t)
=\frac{d}{dt}f(t,y(t))=f_t(t,y(t))+f_y(t,y(t))y'(t) \\
=f_t(t,y(t))+f_y(t,y(t))f(t,y(t)).
$$
The only important point is that it is exactly this expression that will give a second order method, how you denote this is of secondary concern.

For your example you have correctly applied the formula, only it does not make sense to only half-way replace $f$ with its actual expression, you should continue to
$$
f'(t,y)=3(3y-2t)-2=9y-6t-2.
$$

Comment: Yes, or the chain rule, combining $(s,u)\mapsto f(s,u)$ with the map $t\mapsto (t,y(t))$.